# How to sort files in emacs dired?

Tags: sorting, emacs, dired

Emacs dired mode is an easy to use text-based file manager. By default, files are displayed in alphabetical order. Is there a way to sort the files by file size descending order?

Comment: It is explained in this wiki: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Dired#Sort_files and you have more options here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSorting

Comment: @Ehvince Thank you. Wiki is a good place to learn.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may customize the sort order by providing an argument to the `dired-sort-toggle-or-edit` which is bound to the <kbd>s</kbd> keystroke.

So to answer your question, just type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> and pass the `-lS` switches.
You may pass `-lhS` for human readable results.

Comment: The option `l` means "long" and instructs the command to display files in a detailed format, including information such as permissions, owner, group, size, and modification date.

The option `h` means "human-readable" and instructs the command to display file sizes in a more easily understandable format for humans, such as "1K" for 1 kilobyte or "1G" for 1 gigabyte.

The option `S` means "size" and instructs the command to sort files by file size, placing the largest files at the top of the list.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use the extension [dired-quick-sort](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-quick-sort). After setting it up, push "S" to display a sorting menu that offers many different ways to sort, including file size.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the extension.